# Facebook: iOS app sharing failed

Tags: ios, facebook, sharing

The iOS app has got the `Publish_Action` of `Facebook`. The problem is :
when I use the `Test Users` to make a share, it can success.
But when I use the real account to make a share, it always failed. I also check the app is authorized in the real account.
I guess there may be any missing setting in facebook's developer site but I failed to find it.
Any idea?

BTW: I do **Not** use the sdk provided by `Facebook`. I use a 3-rd party service which integrating lots of sharing service and it doesn't show error log in above situation.

----------Update--------------
For the normal account, the facebook shows 
"this does not let the app post to Facebook". But I have get the `Publish_action` ability.
What's wrong?

Comment: Does your Facebook app settings show sandbox mode active ? If it is, you might need to add that user as an administrator, developer or tester in your Facebook app settings.

Comment: yes, I can see the Roles. Should turn off the sandbox mode? where to close it?

Comment: btw, In the "Status && Review", I have made it "available to the general public".